# Close dialog when completed updating on CProgressCtrl

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am using MFC and how do i check Progress bar completed update (100%), i want to close the dialog when completed a task, i am using

```
 if(mProgress.GetPos()==100)
{   

    Sleep(3000);
    EndDialog(IDD_DIALOG_PROGRESS_BAR);

}
```

but it close dialog at progress is about 90%, i know that: The position of the progress bar control is not the physical location on the screen but how to do this? Please help me.

Comment: What is that Sleep(3000) for which is blocking the GUI for 3 seconds?

Comment: What range and step did you set on the CProgressCtrl?

Comment: Why do you check the CProgressCtrl for completion? Normally you have some action going on and on progress you update the CProgressCtrl. So the primary source for completion is your action, not the CProgressCtrl.

Comment: Ok Werner Henze, my program can send files from PC to mobile devices and it have a progress bar to display the progress. when sending file is finished, i want to close progress bar, but the progress bar still can't update to 100% and close.

Comment: You should consider using a separate thread for the processing that may take a while.

Comment: Your program tells the progress bar what to do. Why are you trying to get the progress bar to tell your program what to do?  Go to the place where you set the progress bar and test for 100 there.

Comment: I used progress bar to display the file's percent transfered, my dialog  contains the Progress bar receive a message from main dialog to display progress, i used: mProgress.SetPos(percent); but when percent is 100, the progress bar can't update to 100 before closed.

Comment: I've read all discussion, but I still don't get your point @user3517638 ... What Scott and Werner are trying to tell you, is that when you notify with main dlg to m_Progress to reach 100, you should close your child dlg too. As side note, I would handle the closing of the dialog with OnOK or OnCancel overriding.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your program is too busy with copying to the mobile device so that the user interface is behind its schedule. Try adding this code to your copy loop to give the UI time to catch up:

```
    MSG msg;
    // Handle dialog messages
    while(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
      if(!IsDialogMessage(&msg))
      {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);  
      }
    }
```